# How to declare function for data type that can hold single or list values?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a tree where each node can have 0 - 2 children and leaves contain lists:
`data Test aa = Leaf [aa] | Treenode (TTT aa) (TTT aa) | Empty deriving Show`
For example if `aa` would be `Int` then leaves would hold `[Int]`.

How do I write a function definition that accepts this type of data? I tried:
`f :: (aa -> aa) -> Test aa -> Test aa`
This gives error: `Couldn't match expected type 'aa' with actual type '[aa]'` because `Leaf [aa]` is a list not a single value.

I thought it would't be a problem because function receives argument of type `Test` and the list `[aa]` is the content of the argument `Test` and not the argument itself, if that makes sense.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You *should* be getting a "Not in scope" error for the undefined type `TTT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type should be:

```
data Test aa = Leaf [aa] | Treenode (Test aa) (Test aa) | Empty deriving Show
```

Then, for example, you could create a `map` function with your trees:

```
f :: (aa -> aa) -> Test aa -> Test aa
f _ Empty = Empty
f g (Leaf xs) = Leaf $ map g xs
f g (Treenode x y) = Treenode (f g x) (f g y)

Prelude> f (1+) (Treenode (Leaf [1,2]) (Leaf [3,4]))
Treenode (Leaf [2,3]) (Leaf [4,5])
```

Comment: `f` is just `fmap`, so you may as well define a `Functor` instance for `Tree`.

Comment: Yes, but that was not the purpose of the question. I put this example because it matches with the signature given by @RobertK.